# Can't listen for event on newly created elements

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I can't add an event to a newly created element.
The following code is executed upon `onload`.
It shows the alert "blah" on page refresh for the number of times new elements are created, but these elements are not clickable after loading.
Any ideas?

```
for (var S = 0; S < arrInbound[i][3].length; S++){      
    var namesDiv = document.createElement('div');
    namesDiv.id = S;
    namesDiv.draggable = 'true';
    namesDiv.contenteditable = 'true';
    namesDiv.className = "crewNames";
    //namesDiv.ondragstart = 'dragStart(event)';
    //namesDiv.onblur = 'updateArr(this)';
    namesDiv.onclick = alert("blah");
    namesDiv.innerHTML = arrInbound[i][3][S];
    tagElRight.appendChild(namesDiv)        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is function assignment

```
namesDiv.onclick = function() { alert('a'); } // CORRECT
```

This is function call, `namesDiv.onclick` is **result** of *alert fn*, which is `undefined`

```
namesDiv.onclick = alert('a'); // WRONG
```

---

More simplified example

```js
    var myBar = alert('apple'); //calls alert instantly

    var myFoo = function() {
      alert('banana');
    }

    console.log('myBar', myBar); //logs undefined
    console.log('myFoo', myFoo); //logs fn
```

Comment: That worked! How is it used to call a function somewhere else in the js file?

Comment: @Ethannn sorry didn't understand, you can open new post if there is any other problem, anyway you can attach any function to `window` object, be sure it's defined above of usage

Answer (score 1):

Your onclick is not a function, because you set onclick to result of alert execution. Try next:

```
namesDiv.onclick = function() {alert("blah")};
```